# Matlab decreasing matrix diagonal

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I want to create a matrix where the middle diagonal is symmetrically decreasing to the sides, like this:

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 5 4 3 2
3 4 5 4 3
2 3 4 5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

The matrix has to be 100x100 and the values are between `0` and `1`.
Until now I only get the edges and the middle diagonal, but can't get the idea on how to automatically fill the rest.

```
v = ones(1,100);
green = diag(v);
green(:,1) = fliplr(0:1/99:1);
green(1,:) = fliplr(0:1/99:1);
green(100,:) = 0:1/99:1;
green(:,100) = 0:1/99:1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
N = 100; %// size of your matrix
v = ones(1,N); %// get a vector of ones
D = N*diag(v); %// set the main diagonal
for ii = 1:size(D,1)-1
    tmp = (N-ii)*diag(v(1:end-ii),ii); %//positive direction off-
    tmp2 = (N-ii)*diag(v(1:end-ii),-ii); %//negative direction off-diagonal
    D = D+tmp+tmp2; %// Add them up
end
D = D/N; %// scale values to between 0 and 1
```

The trick here is to use the indexing variable, `ii`, as a counter to simultaneously decrease the multiplication, `N-ii`, decrease the length of `v`, `v(1:end-ii)` and increase the offset of the diagonal within [`diag`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html), `ii` or `-ii`.

Just to verify plot the results using `imagesc(D)`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 7):

To look for a vectorized solution consider using `spdiags()`.

```
n = 5;
A = repmat([1:n-1,n:-1:1],n,1);
B = full(spdiags(A,-n+1:n-1,n,n));
```

This will return:

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 5 4 3 2
3 4 5 4 3
2 3 4 5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

As [@Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5211833/adriaan) pointed out `B = B/n` will transform the matrix values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised no one has recommended the [`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) matrix to you:

```
n = 5;
out = toeplitz(n:-1:1);
```

We get:

```
out = 


     5     4     3     2     1
     4     5     4     3     2
     3     4     5     4     3
     2     3     4     5     4
     1     2     3     4     5
```

If you want to normalize this to `[0,1]`, simply do standard normalization such that:

```
out_new = (out - 1) / (n - 1)
```

... and so:

```
>> out = (out - 1) / (n - 1)

out =

    1.0000    0.7500    0.5000    0.2500         0
    0.7500    1.0000    0.7500    0.5000    0.2500
    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000    0.7500    0.5000
    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000    0.7500
         0    0.2500    0.5000    0.7500    1.0000
```

Answer (score 5):

How about some [`code-golfing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) -

```
n = 5
M = mod(bsxfun(@plus,n:-1:1,(0:n-1)'),n)
out = triu(M)+tril(n-M)
```

For your actual case, since you need to have values in the range `[0,1]`, you can scale `out`, like so -

```
out = (out - 1)/max(out(:)-1)
```

Sample run -

```
>> n = 5;
M = mod(bsxfun(@plus,n:-1:1,(0:n-1)'),n);
out = triu(M)+tril(n-M);
>> out
out =
     5     4     3     2     1
     4     5     4     3     2
     3     4     5     4     3
     2     3     4     5     4
     1     2     3     4     5
>> out = (out - 1)/max(out(:)-1)
out =
            1         0.75          0.5         0.25            0
         0.75            1         0.75          0.5         0.25
          0.5         0.75            1         0.75          0.5
         0.25          0.5         0.75            1         0.75
            0         0.25          0.5         0.75            1
```